Como quitar la "cache de imagenes" en correos de Google
Tengo un sistema que generaba (en tiempo pasado) códigos QR para hacer la 2FA. Pero Google quito el API para hacer QRs y ahora me toca usar otro API.
El siguiente código genera una url de un QR con la API de TEC-IT
public function createQR($nombre, $secreto, $titulo = null){
        $url = 'https://qrcode.tec-it.com/API/QRCode?data=';
        $url_encode = urlencode('otpauth://totp/' . $nombre . '?secret=' . $secreto . '');
        if (isset($titulo)) $url_encode .= urlencode('&issuer=' . urlencode($titulo));
        $params = '&errorcorrection=M&backcolor=%23ffffff&size=medium';
        return $url . $url_encode . $params . '';
    }

El resultado "puro" de esa función es algo como esta url:

https://qrcode.tec-it.com/API/QRCode?data=otpauth%3A%2F%2Ftotp%2Fxxx%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2Axxx%40gmail.com%3Fsecret%3DZIPPVLQ7L7O3W47F%26issuer%3Dauth2FA&errorcorrection=M&backcolor=%23ffffff&size=medium

Hasta ahí todo bien, el problema viene cuando envío el correo de confirmación al usuario, envío el correo desde un Gmail que ya está seteado y funciona bien pero al momento de mostrar la imagen en el correo, la única imagen que no se ve (porque hay otras más en el correo) es la del QR.
Que pasa? que a la url antes mencionada, Google le antepone lo siguiente:

https://ci3.googleusercontent.com/meips/ADKq_Nb1A-ELO6QZ1Hhvb3maIZ-gQW04hB0pgMs38_ocj2UdMA5bTY_17fj7ETO737wRQj4bQoz6wrfb4U9nl6tjmmohauIW-W2LILZ_2DTTEz72zCNZu_vx0_UdFyK-CotpZlWV39s1WK8dxFiQ2ZP68EwGozuYjBApkGOgpzSRE0sd4qARFKaaibS3Ka4jVs8wKv3UbDQz07UQ9FoRxiLZ1vM-1mdrOp3ld1AMVfIsXoip9_Zl3gdvkQzuuM0ygEmUmx5wZAekhaA6nM1sgFTQfR5TolTIc0eKmMQin8hzbIlkULL0qqU-reMyQlMCdLIkjg=s0-d-e1-ft#

Lo que genera una gran url como esta:

https://ci3.googleusercontent.com/meips/ADKq_Nb1A-ELO6QZ1Hhvb3maIZ-gQW04hB0pgMs38_ocj2UdMA5bTY_17fj7ETO737wRQj4bQoz6wrfb4U9nl6tjmmohauIW-W2LILZ_2DTTEz72zCNZu_vx0_UdFyK-CotpZlWV39s1WK8dxFiQ2ZP68EwGozuYjBApkGOgpzSRE0sd4qARFKaaibS3Ka4jVs8wKv3UbDQz07UQ9FoRxiLZ1vM-1mdrOp3ld1AMVfIsXoip9_Zl3gdvkQzuuM0ygEmUmx5wZAekhaA6nM1sgFTQfR5TolTIc0eKmMQin8hzbIlkULL0qqU-reMyQlMCdLIkjg=s0-d-e1-ft#https://qrcode.tec-it.com/API/QRCode?data=otpauth%3A%2F%2Ftotp%2Fxxx%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2A%2Axxx%40gmail.com%3Fsecret%3DZIPPVLQ7L7O3W47F%26issuer%3Dauth2FA&errorcorrection=M&backcolor=%23ffffff&size=medium

Y lo que obviamente no permite ver el QR en el correo.
Esto se debe en parte al Cacheo de Imágenes de Google que explican acá
Alguien ha sabido como solventar este problema? Entiéndase que la url de la imagen generada se envía pura desde el sistema, pero cuando pasa por los filtros de Google es que le antepone lo antes mencionado, es decir de mi sistema sale bien y Google la daña.
Alguna idea de que hacer??

Y si envías la imagen adjunta al correo en vez de por la URL?

Adjunta no se vería directamente en el cuerpo del correo y se tendría que bajar o ver el adjunto cosa que resta usabilidad, no entiendo porque las otras imágenes (que también van por url) si se ven, pero el QR no

La API de https://qrcode.tec-it.com da problemas, utiliza la api de https://quickchart.io/qr-code-api/ y el resultado será el esperado.
public function createQR($nombre, $secreto, $titulo = null){
        $url = 'https://quickchart.io/qr?text=';
        $url_encode = urlencode('otpauth://totp/' . $nombre . '?secret=' . $secreto . '');
        if (isset($titulo)) $url_encode .= urlencode('&issuer=' . urlencode($titulo));
        $params = '&size=300';
        return $url . $url_encode . $params . '';
    }


Yo lo uso así y no tengo problemas con el cache de Google.
